# How to force flutter to use a old version of dependency?

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

After migration on flutter 1.17 application wont build. Circular check box is causing a error because with the migration on flutter 1.17 it is upgraded to 1.0.2 and even though i am using 1.0.1 in my app flutter still takes it as 1.0.2 and its causing trouble. 
[Link to github issues](https://github.com/mashnoon33/circular_check_box/issues/5) This clears what my problem is and what's the solution but i don't know how to force or degrade a version. Changing the version in yaml isn't working. I've also tried using dependency_overrides: 1.0.1 but still error.
[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can specify the specific version you want to use in your `pubspec.yaml` by not including a caret `^` before the version number as we usually do. [See this](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies) for more information of selecting package versions.

An example for your use:

```
dependencies:
  package_name: '1.0.1'
```

You should then run `flutter pub upgrade` to ensure that the package that will be used updates, though this may be unecessary.

Comment: I've tried this but its not working. I've edited my question and added the image have a look

Comment: @AhmadHassan Did you try my solution? What is the result there? You cannot use caret notation here.

Comment: Ahh thanks @Christopher It's working now, just removed the caret notation. I'm absolutely brand new to flutter. Can you tell me why there is caret notation with every dependency as you can see in the picture?

Comment: @AhmadHassan you can read more about it in the link. Caret notation basically gets the latest non breaking version of the package. It seems the person who created the package made a mistake in your case.

Comment: in my case, i didnt run a flutter upgrade, since i was using an older version and didnt want to cause any more conflicts, after removing the caret notation, I ran flutter pub get, and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 10):

You can also use dependency_overrides to override dependency, with this you can use both the version of your dependency at once.

```
dependencies:
 package_name : latest_version

dependency_overrides:
 package_name : older_version
```

Comment: They can't exactly use both at once, they'll be able to use *only* the overridden version. The normally declared one could be used by other packages that depend on it in the user's dependency graph.